# tvOS (TVML): custom UIView in TVML

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I'm trying to use a custom UIView by registering a template:

```
TVElementFactory.registerViewElementClass(TVViewElement.self, elementName: "view1")
```

i then override the `makeView` `TVInterfaceCreating` protocol method:

```
func makeView(element: TVViewElement, existingView: UIView?) -> UIView? {

        switch element.name {

        case "view1":
            let view = View1()
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
            return view

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

My Javascript file is as follows:

```
<document>
     <divTemplate>
          <view1></view1>
     </divTemplate>
</document>
```

But i get an empty view. Nothing is displayed!

How do i go about my custom UIView in TVML?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this???